# Rewarding with ERC721 tokens

Tags: nft

Imagine you own some foundation, and for every donation you want to give donor an NFT as gift. So taking gas price in mind, how would you solve this problem for 10k+ users?

Comment: I would move to Polygon

Comment: Agreed, doing this on mainnet would require you to sell a few organs to pay for gas no matter how you do it.

Comment: Yes, the right thing to do is to use a network with low gas costs

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to be smart and tell the user that he has got a beautiful NFT and let him collect it himself!Those who want NFT are willing to spend a little gas, and those who don't want NFT don't need any.

Of course you should also deploy the contract on a relatively cheap chain, otherwise there will still be a lot of users who don't want to claim the NFT.

God bless you.

Comment: Is there any way to have donation part on L1 and NFT part on L2?